# Putting mapped variable in source for an Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecma

I have searched through stack and no one has seem to ask this question based on what I want to achieve. I am mapping through an array and I want to do the name of the mapped variable as the source of the image, i.e I'll concatenate it with `.jpg`

This is what I attempted below, but it brings this error `calls to`require`expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found:`require('./' + herb.name + '.jpg')`.` , what may I be doing wrong

```
 const herbs = this.state.record.map((herb) =>
 <View key={herb.id} style={BackStyles.herb_box}>
 <Image style={BackStyles.image} source={require('./'+herb.name+'.jpg')}/>
 <View style={{flexDirection: 'column',}}><Text style={BackStyles.header}>{herb.name}</Text> <Text style={BackStyles.sub}>{herb.bot}</Text></View>
            </View>
        );
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require("./" + herb.name + ".jpg")`.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work as images need to be statically known up front, so the resolver to knows from where to load the assets.

**In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.**

More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources)

```
var imageMap = {
    "herb1":  require('path.to.img.jpg'),
    "herb2":  require('path.to.img.jpg'),
};
<Image style={BackStyles.image} source={imageMap[herb.name]}/>
```

other option you can **try** is with the *uri* property
You can use the *uri* property to define a dynamic image within your resource folder in the project.

```
<Image source={{uri: `${herb.name}.jpg`}} />
```

Comment: So i can't use an object name as a source for an Image?

Comment: nop, you can create a mapping function/object with all resources defined upfront, that would work

Comment: How will I do that

Comment: What I want to do is to edit that 'path.to.img', that's my main aim

Comment: do you think using `uri: imageName` will do the job

Comment: yes, just updating my answer for the second option, that you try with that

Comment: Thanks @ztadic91, Last question :), what's the resource folder, and is it different for android and ios